# Error in heatmap.2(as.matrix(data)) : `x' must be a numeric matrix

Tags: r, statistics, cluster-computing, relationship, heatmap

I am trying to create a heatmap of the genomic relationship matrix where the rows and columns are clustered using a hierarchical clustering method.

I am trying the following script:

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\Amanda\\Documents\\Mestrado-                    ESALQ\\RESULTADOS_FINAL_2017\\LD_Coutinho\\relacionamento_ind")
data_orig<-as.data.frame(read.table("G_Orig.txt"))
colnames(data_orig)<-c("id1","id2","Relationship")
nrow(data_orig) #156816

################Transform into matrix with animals in row and column
library(reshape)
data<-cast(data_orig, id1 ~ id2)
y<-as.data.frame(data[,-397])


#Run heatmap.2 on this matrix
library(gplots)
test <- heatmap.2(as.matrix(y))

y[rev(test$rowInd), test$colInd]
## Row clustering (adjust here distance/linkage methods to what yo need)
hr <- hclust(as.dist(1-cor(t(y), method="pearson")),
method="complete")

## Column clustering (adjust here distance/linkage methods to what you
need!)
hc <- hclust(as.dist(1-cor(y, method="spearman")), method="complete")

## Plot heatmap
heatmap.2(y, Rowv=as.dendrogram(hr), Colv=as.dendrogram(hc),
scale="row", density.info="none", trace="none")

## Return matrix with row/column sorting as in heatmap
y[rev(hr$labels[hr$order]), hc$labels[hc$order]]
```

My data_orig is a data with 3 columns: ind1, ind2 and relationship.

What can I do?

Comment: It'd be easier if you'd give a reproducible example. '

Comment: `str(data)`; is all data actually numeric? As the error you get seems to indicate it's not

Comment: Yes. All data is numeric. The animal identification also is numeric. I only have NA when the animal is the same of ID1 and ID2

Comment: Yes. All data is numeric. The id numbers also. But I have some NA.

Comment: Perhaps the `NAs` are the problem? I am not familiar with what you're doing, but try: `test <- heatmap.2(as.matrix(y), na.rm = TRUE)`. `na.rm = TRUE` would remove all NAs, perhaps heatmap.2 cannot handle those. It might be worth the try, just to see if that is the problem. If it is, then you can at least work with that and think about what you'd want to do with the `NAs`.

Comment: Tell me if it works or not :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your attention. The error was that after 'cast' function, the animal id stay as a column. It is not working because the heatmap.2 not working with this column. But thank you so much.